# Why do I have to embed my libraries inside my applications binary for them to work?

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, static-libraries, dylib

So I followed this tutorial:

http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/

Everything went fine except when I went to run the program I got the following error:

```
> dyld: Library not loaded:
> @rpath/SwiftFramework.framework/SwiftFramework   Referenced from:
> /Users/bluke/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40677D10-F22B-4AE4-B767-06439AB7887A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C6A5F76-C666-4B69-9353-A0ABD7DA085B/UseFramework.app/UseFramework
> Reason: image not found
```

I was able to solve this problem by adding the framework as an embedded binary, but I don't understand why this was needed to solve the problem.

I thought that the framework would be included in my application bundle as a dynamically linked library (i.e. not embedded in my application's binary directly) and then linked at run time. Is this assumption incorrect?

Just in case my question was unclear, I've added the following pictures.

This is what was producing the error:

[image: This is what was producing the error]

If I add the framework to the embedded binaries it works:

[image: This works]

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that the framework would be included in my application
>   bundle as a dynamically linked library (i.e. not embedded in my
>   application's binary directly) and then linked at run time. Is this
>   assumption incorrect?

**Yes,** it's incorrect. iOS apps link 3rd party frameworks statically, not dynamically. This prevents apps from downloading and dynamically linking code that hasn't been vetted by the app store review process.

Comment: Hmmm so does this mean that every 3rd party lib/framework has to be embedded in the binary? And is embedding in the binary apple's term for statically linking?

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question, which is about an Apple provided framework.

Comment: it is actually not about an apple provided framework, this is a custom framework

Answer (score 1):

This allows apps coded in Swift to run on devices running a version of iOS pre-dating Swift (earlier than iOS8).

Non-Apple frameworks can be embedded on iOS8 and above only.

It is also nice to add a prefix the the name identifying the developer organization so as to avoid comflicts and confusion. "SwiftFramework" looks so much like an Apple framework.

Comment: I had to do exactly the same thing with an objective c framework

Comment: I think I am missing something, what exactly does it mean to embed a library as a binary and how does it differ from statically linking a library?